# Loop and calculate with numbers from 2 file in Python 3.6

Tags: python, file, loops

Hi guys i need to write a program that have the following instructions:

1. Read input files called lengths.txt and widths.txt
2. The file (lengths.txt) has lengths in centimetres. The file (widths.txt) has widths in
   centimetres. Line 1 in each file represents length and width of first rectangle. Similarly, Line 2 in each file represents length and width of 2nd rectangle – and so on.
3. print length and width of each rectangle.
4. Your program will loop through the file numbers and read all the numbers and
   calculates the area of every rectangle using the formula:
   Area of a Rectangle = Length x Width
5. Display all numbers in the following format (please note that you should use the numbers in the rectangle.txt): Rectangle 1  length x width = area. For example:
   Rectangle 1  40 x 12 = 480
   Rectangle 2  10 x 8 = 80
   ...
6. Display the average area for all rectangles in the text file using the formula: Average = sum or all areas / number of rectangles

My code is like:

```
 with open("C:/WebP/lengths.txt") as a, open("C:/WebP/widths.txt") as b:
        for x, y in zip(a, b):
            x = x.strip()
            y = y.strip()

        print("length: {0}\twidth: {1}".format(x, y))

    a.close()
    b.close()
```

I can't get through point 4. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You have the formula.  You have the numbers.  Where are you stuck?  "I can't get through point 4" is more of a question for a local tutor, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Our tutor give us this as an assessment. Sorry guys I didn't read it just want the easy path to finish cause I can't find solution on the net in the last 3 hour. I mean how to write a loop that go through the lines and calculates the area one by one from two txt. I know how to do it if I have just one txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few points to note

- You do not need to use `.close()` method when you are opening the
  file using `with`
- You need to convert them to `int` (assuming your example output) before
  performing the multiplication operation
- Since you need the rectangle number, you can define a variable count
  and increment it every iteration

```
with open("lengths.txt",'r') as a, open("widths.txt",'r') as b:
    count = 1
    area_list = []
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        x = int(x.strip())
        y = int(y.strip())
        area = x*y
        count += 1
        area_list.append(area)
        print('Rectangle {} : {} x {} = {}'.format(count, x, y, area))

 average_area = sum(area_list)/len(area_list)
```

Comment: anytime @seeelph

Answer (score 0):

ADD THIS

```
 with open("C:/WebP/lengths.txt") as a, open("C:/WebP/widths.txt") as b:
    sum_t, area_t = 0,0
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        x = x.strip()
        y = y.strip()
        area = float(x)*float(y) #int(x) * int(y)
        area_t += area
        sum_t += 1

        print("length: {0}\twidth: {1}".format(x, y))
        print("Rectangle %d length %s width %s:%d"%(sum_t, x,y, area ))


    a.close()
    b.close()
    print(" Average =",str(area_t/sum_t))
```